# get current system volume level on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, volume

Is there a way I can get the current system volume level on the iPhone?

I'm thinking maybe there's a way to make an `MPVolumeView` and get the value from that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
musicPlayer = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

currentVolume = musicPlayer.volume;
```

This is now deprecated as of iOS8.0 so try the following

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
CGFloat volume = audioSession.outputVolume;
```

Comment: This returns the music volume level, not the system volume level.

Comment: `iPodMusicPlayer` and `volume` are deprecated, is there a newer way?

Answer (score 2):

Celestial.framework has an `AVSystemController` class that lets you get and set the current volume. Unfortunately it is a private class so Apple won't accept it in App Store submissions

If it helps, you can abuse the public `MPVolumeView` class a bit: http://www.stormyprods.com/blogger/2008/09/proper-usage-of-mpvolumeview-class.html

Comment: Hi, rpetrich , is it possible to change the systemwide volume via the MPVolumeView ...

Comment: Robin: yes, it's possible, but don't expect to have your app in the store if you do (and there's much simpler methods that provide easy access in Celestial)

Answer (score 0):

Add MediaPlayer Framework into your project

[image]

.h (Header file)

```
{

  MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer; 

}
```

.m (implementation file)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

//get device volume level

   musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

   float deviceVolumeLevel = musicPlayer.volume;

   NSLog(@"Current device volume level : %f",deviceVolumeLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3.0

..

```
import AVKit
..
    // get current level:
    let  audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let volume : Float = audioSession.outputVolume
```