# How to detect an Iphone/Ipod volume level?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, volume

Hi there I have an app that play short sound clips as the main functionality.  If the user happened to have the volume to mute or too low,  they won't be able to hear the sound clip and the app will appear to be broken.

Is there a way to detect the sound volume so that i can display a message to the user to indicate that their sound is too low or off and they need to adjust the volume?

I searched through stackoverflow and google and it seems like i can only find article on how to change the volume or detecting volume changed event.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get current system volume level on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572606/get-current-system-volume-level-on-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

It has the property `volume` which will let you read the volume level.

Comment: I am sure the volume property of the MPMusicPlayerController has nothing to do with the device volume level. It is just the level the music will play relative to the current level of the device.

Comment: After implementing the MPMusicPlayerController,  I was able to accomplished what I wanted to do.  thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, in iOS6 [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].volume always returns 0.625 or 1.0 if headphones plugged in