# I want to determine the music level of ipod music

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get current system volume level on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572606/get-current-system-volume-level-on-iphone)

I want to take sound level of ipod music in my application. how can i determine the level of music when it goes high and low?

Comment: Why is this question a duplicate? It is not asking for the current value of the volume knob, it's asking "how do I read streaming audio data from itunes"

Answer (score 0):

```
musicPlayer = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

currentVolume = musicPlayer.volume;
```

Comment: no i dont want volume ... i want level metering