# How to know if volume hardware control is up or down in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, hardware, volume

Is possible to detect if volume hardware control is down or up? i need to play sound on button touch in my application, and i want to send a message to user that volume is down and to use this app he need to change hardware

EDIT:

I need to do something like this:

```
BOOL VolumeHardwareControl = getHardwareInfo();
if(VolumeHardwareControl==NO){
    message: "Attention! To play sound you need to turn hardware on!"
}else
   playSound();
```

Comment: Lots of duplicate questions on this topic, Jack.  Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572606/get-current-system-volume-level-on-iphone) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4).

Comment: these topic says about get current volume, not hardware. volume could be down but hardware on..

Comment: If you found an answer [you are welcome to post and accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: i have to create answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef);
CFStringRef route;

AudioSessionGetProperty (
                 kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute,
                 &routeSize,
                 &route
                );

if (route == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Silent switch is on");
}
```