# How to check the iPads sound level

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get current system volume level on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572606/get-current-system-volume-level-on-iphone)

I am working on an application, which includes sound. During runtime I would like to check the sound level to be able to give the user feedback by showing a pop-up with the text "the volume is too low" if the sound level is too low (just an example). I know how to check if the sound is muted or not, but how to I check the sound level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

```
MPMusicPlayerController myVolumeTester = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

float volume = myVolumeTester.volume;
```

This gives you a value between 0.0 and 1.0 so you can then do a check

```
if(volume < 0.2) {
    // display "volume is too low"
}
if(volume > 0.9) {
    // watch your ears!
}
```