# How can I get current volume value in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want get the current value of my iphone from my audio player in objective c. But I can't get this because is deprecated.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
musicPlayer.volume //This is deprecated
```

There are some alternatives?

Comment: This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7879500/558575

Answer (score 0):

As written in the developer docs you should use the VolumeView ([Seen here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624567-volume))
Because it is a view, you cannot get the current value. I'm not sure, but maybe this code works (not tested):

```
MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];
for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        UISlider *slider = (UISlider*) view;
        CGFloat volume = slider.value; // this is the current volume
    }
}
```

If this does not work, you can set the volume of you application by setting

```
slider.value = 1.0f;
```

in the for loop.